# Is this any condition type in ruby? !!() , !() , !0, !!0

Tags: ruby, irb

I was just playing with irb. And I tried such syntax which returns me `true`/`false`

Can anyone please describe me why and how this behavior happened? Is this any condition type?

For Eg:

```
 > !!()
 => false 
 > !()
 => true 
 > !0
 => false 
 > !!0
 => true
```

I appreciate if anyone can describe me this syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
()
# => nil
```

parenthesis are precedence 'operator', parenthesis with no expression return `nil`, as you see. So no wonder that:

```
!()
# => true
!!() # == !(!()) == !(true)
# => false
```

`0` is *truthy* in Ruby (in fact, only `nil` and `false` are *falsy*):

```
puts 'truthy' if 0
truthy
# => nil
```

so the opposite of `0` is `false`:

```
!0
# => false
```

and `!!0` is opposite to `false`:

```
!!0 # == !(!0) == !(false)
# => true
```

Comment: In ruby, only `false` and `nil` are falsey.

Comment: @Aetherus you're right and I think it's worth noting in my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MarekLipka : Thank you for your well described answered.

Comment: Note that [`!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) is a method, so `!!0` is equivalent to `0.send(:!@).send(:!@)`. That might be easier to understand.

Comment: @MarekLipka : Thank you for your well described answered.

Comment: @Stefan : Yeah it makes more easier to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

() evaluates as `nil`, which evaluates similar to `false`. Adding the ! Operator (once, twice, or however many times) simply changes `false` to `true` and `true` to `false`...